# Blowfish and undefined reference to `BF_set_key'

Tags: c++, openssl, codeblocks, undefined-reference, blowfish

I have installed Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.1b and Visual C++ 2008 Redistributables from this page http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html and added compiler (`C:\OpenSSL-Win64\include`) and linker paths (`C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin`, `C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib`, `C:\OpenSSL-Win64`) to Code::Blocks, but I still cannot compile my program.

Source code:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <openssl/blowfish.h>

int main() {
    const char * key = "aaabbbcccdddeeefffggghh";
    BF_KEY bfKey;

    BF_set_key(&bfKey, strlen(key), (const unsigned char *) key);

    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `BF_set_key'|
```

I tried to add `-lssl`, `-lopenssl`, `-llibssl`, `-lcrypto`, but it doesn't work. Then I can see another error:

```
ld.exe||cannot find -lssl|
```

I have no idea (and Google also) what to do. Any ideas what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you configured it properly. It seems like you also have to add the libraries your project is using somewhere in Build Options, on top of setting the library directories. Does this help? http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/

Comment: I saw this page and I had tried this solution, now I have tried to add all (I am not sure which one is responsible for what I need) libraries from lib/ as in step 5, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the GCC compiler (MinGW) with Code::Blocks you have to change the library sear directory (C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib) to C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\MinGW and to link the library that have the Blowfish function you must use -leay32 (in your case probably is -leay64).

Inside the directory C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\MinGW there are 2 files with the .def extensin that have the list of functions exported by each library (libeay32.a/libeay64.a  and ssleay32.a/ssleay64.a), by the way if you use the -l option the file must be called lib.a; the if you want to use any of the functions on the library ssleay32.a/ssleay64.a you must link the file directly (for example C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\MinGW\ssleay32.a) or append lib to the name of the file.

Comment: There's a problem. I haven't got MinGW/ in lib/ - just VC/ Also when I try to add -leay64 Code::Blocks shows 'cannot find -leay64' and for -leay32 'C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin/libeay32.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized'. In lib/ I see only *.lib files, no *.a ones.